# Two dimensional array 4x5 matrix

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I recently dove into Java and came across two dimensional arrays. For a while now, I'm trying to understand this code:

```
   int twoD[][]= new int[4][5];
int i, j, k = 0;

for(i=0; i<4; i++)
for(j=0; j<5; j++) {
    twoD[i][j] = k;
 k++; }

for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
  for(j=0; j<5; j++)
    System.out.print(twoD[i][j] + " ");
  System.out.println();
```

The output is

0 1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8 9

10 11 12 13 14

15 16 17 18 19

I just can't figure out how the chronology of this code works. I understand that for each row 5 column outputs should be made, but how it this achieved in steps?

MANY THANKS!

Roeland
Amsterdam

Comment: What do you mean "chronology"?

Comment: I think he meant flow/execution of the program

Comment: it's mainly that I don't understand in what order the for loops are executed. What route leads to the order of the output 1, 2 etc. Sorry I;ve only been doing this for a week...going well until now

Comment: `k++;`. Starts with `0`, adds `1` each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

The first loop iterates over each row and the second nested loop is for each element in this row and each time setting the value of k to this array and incrementing by 1

Comment: Thanks! this made it clearer as well. But I still don't get the running order of what's happening step by step in this code. And how is k used for the output? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

think about `int[4][1]` output would be

```
0
1
2
3
```

then think about `int[4][2]`

```
0 1
2 3
4 5
6 7
```

See the pattern now?

Answer (score 0):

By Chronology you mean the sequence in which the array works, I assume:

```
 int twoD[][]= new int[4][5];
```

which is a short form for the following:

```
int[][] twoD= new int[4][];
twoD[0] = new int[5];
twoD[1] = new int[5];
twoD[2] = new int[5];
twoD[3] = new int[5];The arrays in most of the computer lanaguages will start with the index 0.
```

And two dimensional arrays has to arrays in it -  int[4][5] has two parameters 4 and 5. That means it has 4 rows and 5 columns.
For example the two dimensional array you created looks like this:

```
int[][] two = new int[][]{
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4},
{5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
{10, 11 12, 13, 14},
{15, 16, 17, 18, 19}
};
```

The first loop

```
for(i=0; i<4; i++)
```

takes care of looping through the rows and the second for loop

```
for(j=0; j<5; j++)
```

loops through the columns.

Since you are printing the for loop's iterating values like 0,1,2,3 etc... the output is like the one which you get.

I would personally suggest you to have a hands-on in single dimensional array, like
int[] array = {0,1,2,3,4}

use a for loop like

```
for(j=0; j<5; j++) 
 System.out.println(array[j]);
```

this will print

0 
1 
2
3 
4

this will make your learning interesting.
cheers!

Comment: Thanks! But still not totally clear...about the hierarchy of the for loops, what happens and is being outputted sequentially? Sorry, I'm so new to Java, I'm looking for really simple answers at this point.

Comment: may be this video could you explain better on 2d array -
[2d Array explaained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-DhUO3xNYQ)

Answer (score 0):

'`i`' varies from [0 - 4) and for each value of i, (through the inner for loop) `j` varies from [0-5). So the (i,j) pair go from (0,0),(0,1)..(0,4),(1,0),(1,1)......(3,4).

`'twoD[i][j] = k'` assigns the jth column of ith row of twoD array with the calue k. k starts from '0' and increments by 1 each time (via `k++`). So the value of k(and hence `twoD[i][j]`) goes from 0 - 19 where `twoD[0][0] = 0` and `twoD[3][4] = 19`.

If want to see how k increments add this statement - System.out.print(k); before twoD[i][j] = k; and add ' System.out.println();' after 'k++; }'